# How to tell when a Postgres table was clustered and what indexes were used

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I've been impressed by the performance improvements achieved with clustering, but not with how long it takes.

I know clustering needs to be rebuilt if a table or partition is changed after the clustering, but unless I've made a note of when I last clustered a table, how can I tell when I need to do it again?

I can use this query to tell me what table(s) have one or more clustered indexes

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_index i ON i.indrelid = c.oid
WHERE  relkind = 'r' AND relhasindex AND i.indisclustered
```

My questions are.

- How can I tell which indexes have been clustered?
- Is there any way of finding out exactly when a table was last clustered?
- How can I tell if a clustered index is still 'valid', or in other words, how can tell how much a table/index has changed enough that I need to re-build the cluster.

I've noticed that it takes just as long to re-build a clustered index as it does to build it in the first place (even if the table hasn't been touched in the meantime). So I want to avoid re-clustering unless I know the table needs it.

---

UPDATE for clarity (I hope)

If I use this command....

```
CLUSTER tableA USING tableA_idx1;
```

- How can I find out at a later date which index was referenced i.e.
  tableA_idx1 (the table has multiple indexes defined)?
- Is it recorded anywhere *when* this command was run?
- I know that the cluster may need to be rebuilt/refreshed/recreated (not sure of the correct phraseology) occasionally using **CLUSTER tableA** when the table undergoes changes. Is there anyway of knowing when the table has changed so much that the clustering no longer helps?

Comment: "*How can I tell which indexes have been clustered?*" makes not sense. An index is never "clustered" in Postgres. If you want find out which indexes were _used_ for a `cluster` command, then your query will already do that (as it only returns tables that have been "clustered" by an index) Also there is no such thing as "a cluster" in Postgres, so you can't "rebuild the cluster". `cluster` simply re-arranges the rows in the table to have the same physical order as the the index entries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To tell which index was last used to cluster the table, use the [`pg_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html) system catalog.

Query the table for all indexes that belong to your table and see which one has `indisclustered` set. A table can only be clustered by a single index at a time.

There is no way to find out *when* the table was last clustered, but that's not very interesting anyway. What you want to know is how good the clustering still is.

To find that, query the [`pg_stats`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html) line for the column on which you clustered. If `correlation` is close to 1, you are still good. The smaller the value gets, the more clustering is indicated.

Comment: @Laurenze Albe - thank you! The reason I asked about when the table was clustered is that in the absence of better indicators, it gives me a way of estimating the likelihood of the cluster still being 'good' - using the correlation you mention seems a much better way!

Comment: Cross referencing my own answer to a related question on SuperUser since it took me a bit to figure out exactly which columns and syntax to use for @laurenz-albe 's overview: https://superuser.com/a/1718115/1233105